# ASP.NET Page Routing - URL Parameters stripped from target resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

ASP.NET c# project... trying to do a very simple page route.

Please note that I know this is NOT actually doing any dynamic routing... I have the id hard coded like this for a reason.

Example:

```
  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "ABC", "~/Test.aspx?id=101");
```

I can browse to http://www.mysite.com/ABC  no problems, the page Test.aspx loads, the routing is working as expected.

BUT... where has my `id=101` gone?

```
  Request.QueryString["id"] \\ is null...
  Page.RouteData.Values["id"] \\ is null...
```

How can I get hold of the hard coded id in my target resource for the routing?

Comment: Going to try adding "DataTokens" and see how that goes...

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by passing DataTokens.

In my real world scenario I don't know what the URL parameters will be (there could be just the "id" like in my question... or there could be others, sometimes none), so I have to do the following:

First check to see if there is a "?" character in the routing target... if there is, then:

1. Run the string after the "?" character through HttpUtility.ParseQueryString
2. Then, loop through that collection and add them to a System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
3. Then finally add the route, with the DataTokens property set to the RouteValueDictionary